# Excessive PHP errors in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have Joomla 2.5 installed on Windows 7 with Apache 2 and PHP 5. I have countless PHP errors in the log like the following:

```
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP Strict standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\ammon_dev\ammon\plugins\system\jquery\jquery.php on line 24
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP Stack trace:   
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\ammon_dev\ammon\administrator\index.php:0    
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP   2. JAdministrator->route() C:\ammon_dev\ammon\administrator\index.php:40    
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP   3. JApplication->triggerEvent() C:\ammon_dev\ammon\administrator\includes\application.php:106   
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP   4. JDispatcher->trigger() C:\ammon_dev\ammon\libraries\joomla\application\application.php:670    
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP   5. JEvent->update() C:\ammon_dev\ammon\libraries\joomla\event\dispatcher.php:161    
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP   6. call_user_func_array() C:\ammon_dev\ammon\libraries\joomla\event\event.php:71    
[01-Sep-2012 19:33:55 UTC] PHP   7. plgSystemJquery->onAfterRoute() C:\ammon_dev\ammon\libraries\joomla\event\event.php:71
```

I tried disabling error logging in `php.ini`:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Unfortunately that does not make a difference.

Joomla isn’t in debug mode, and I am sure that I’m editing the correct copy of `php.ini` because other changes I make to it take effect.

Any ideas why I am getting so many errors or how to stop it from exploding the log?

Comment: Your question is how to *hide* the errors instead of how to *fix* them? Did you examine the messages and try to figure out why you are getting them in the first place? From the sample log you provided, it looks like your copy of JQuery is the cause (did you make any changes or use third-party versions)? You could try updating JQuery or try Joomla 3. Also check their forums for information on this (if you are using the default installation, then you are [unlikely to be the only one to see it](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ajoomla.org+strict+standards)). You can also report it as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following setting instead:

```
error_reporting = (E_ALL & ~ E_ERROR)
```

It will report all problems except for errors and strict.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error with your system plugin **plgSystemJquery**. If you go ahead and disable that you should be good.

If you are unable to get to the backend... you can just go to the FTP of your website

ROOT/plugins/system/ find a folder with something in name jQuery or something like that and rename it and see if the error goes away.